# Error: could not convert string 'X' to float64

Tags: python, string, numpy

I just want to convert a text to a list of lists using numpy, but the text contains the string: 'X'

> Error: could not convert string 'X' to float64.

I have a text file that contains this:

```
5 3 X X 7 X X X X
6 X X 1 9 5 X X X
X 9 8 X X X X 6 X
8 X X X 6 X X X 3
4 X X 8 X 3 X X 1
7 X X X 2 X X X 6
X 6 X X X X 2 8 X
X X X 4 1 9 X X 5
X X X X 8 X X 7 9
```

And I want to convert this text to a list of lists using numpy
This is my code:

```
import numpy as np

file = input('Enter the file name: '))
list = np.loadtxt(file)
print(list)
```

Expected output:

```
[['5','3','X','X','7','X','X','X','X'],
['6','X','X','1','9','5','X','X','X'],
['X','9','8','X','X','X','X','6','X'],
['8','X','X','X','6','X','X','X','3'],
['4','X','X','8','X','3','X','X','1'],
['7','X','X','X','2','X','X','X','6'],
['X','6','X','X','X','X','2','8','X'],
['X','X','X','4','1','9','X','X','5'],
['X','X','X','X','8','X','X','7','9']]
```

Comment: To which float do you want to convert 'X'?

Comment: No, X is not one of the possible float values

Comment: Please show expected output.

Comment: Sorry I explained myself wrong. I would like to leave 'X' as a string, simply. Ty mate.

Comment: Ok, give me a sec @user19077881

Comment: there is the expected output mate.

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow. I can't understand. It seems as though you expect `numpy.loadtxt` to create an ordinary Python nested list (of lists, of strings). **Why**? Did you try to **read the documentation** for `numpy.loadtxt`, in order to understand what it does? What is your understanding of the **purpose of** Numpy, and in particular, of how Numpy arrays work? Why do you want to use Numpy for this project, and what advantage do you think it could offer?

Answer (score 1):

Specify the `dtype=str` option in `np.loadtxt`.

```
import numpy as np

file = input('Enter the file name: ')
list = np.loadtxt(file, dtype=str)
print(list)
```

This should give:

```
[['5' '3' 'X' 'X' '7' 'X' 'X' 'X' 'X']
 ['6' 'X' 'X' '1' '9' '5' 'X' 'X' 'X']
 ['X' '9' '8' 'X' 'X' 'X' 'X' '6' 'X']
 ['8' 'X' 'X' 'X' '6' 'X' 'X' 'X' '3']
 ['4' 'X' 'X' '8' 'X' '3' 'X' 'X' '1']
 ['7' 'X' 'X' 'X' '2' 'X' 'X' 'X' '6']
 ['X' '6' 'X' 'X' 'X' 'X' '2' '8' 'X']
 ['X' 'X' 'X' '4' '1' '9' 'X' 'X' '5']
 ['X' 'X' 'X' 'X' '8' 'X' 'X' '7' '9']]
```